# Google Map API v3 Disappearing when included in a template

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3, twig

I'm not sure whether it's due to the twig template i'm using or other causes, may be Jquery or css. But I was just following how to embed simple Google Map from [this official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).

When i put the codes in separate html files, i got the map showing and working like a charm. However when I included it in my twig template, the map became disappearing. Sometimes i got the div of the map showing very fast and then disappearing immediately.

I just tried to put a text "this is the map" into that div so i can observe and make sure its state (disappearing or showing), yet i still got it disappearing (the text not showing).

When i commented this line

```
// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

i got the div (and the text of course) showing but not loading the map for sure.
Basically i'm not a front-end developer, so i can not figure out how it can be.

This is my page.

```
{% extends 'YastafeedContentBundle::base_regform.html.twig' %}

{% block content1 %}
<div id="page-title">
  <span class="title">{% block page_title %} Kajian Baru {% endblock %}</span>
  <span class="subtitle">{% block page_subtitle %} Agendakan kajian baru {% endblock %}</span>
</div>
<!-- ENDS title -->
<!-- column (left)-->
<div class="one-column">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  {% block stylesheets %}
  <style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
  </style>
  <link href="/bundles/nova/css/tokeninput/token-input-facebook.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  {{ form_stylesheet(descForm) }}
  {{ form_stylesheet(jadwalForm) }}
  {{ form_stylesheet(lokasiForm) }}
  {{ form_stylesheet(posterForm) }}
  {% endblock %}

  {% block javascripts %}
  <!-- page-content -->
  <!-- form -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/nova/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/nova/js/form-validation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/nova/js/tokeninput/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
  {{ form_javascript(descForm) }}
  {{ form_javascript(jadwalForm) }}
  {{ form_javascript(posterForm) }}
  <script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  {% endblock %}

  <form id="kajianForm" class="contact-form" action="{{ path('kajian_create') }}" method="post">
    <p class="header">Deskripsi Umum</p>
    {{ form_widget(descForm) }}
  </form>

    <div class="agm_google_maps" id="map-70b9d4ed8dc157a52a5b8949e219c8e3"></div>
  <form id="lokasiForm" class="contact-form" action="{{ path('lokasi_create') }}" method="post">
    <p class="header">Lokasi</p>
    {{ form_widget(lokasiForm) }}
  </form>
    <div id="map_canvas">this is the map</div>
</div>

<div class="one-column">
  <form id="posterForm" class="contact-form" action="{{ path('gambar_create') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p class="header">Gambar Fitur</p>
    {{ form_widget(descForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(posterForm) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server" />
  </form>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
      <div class="percent">0%</div >

  </div>

  <div id="status"></div>

  <form id="jadwalForm" class="contact-form" action="{{ path('jadwal_create') }}"  method="post">
    <p class="header">Jadwal</p>
    {{ form_widget(jadwalForm) }}
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" tabindex="5" value="ADD">TAMBAH</button>
  </form>

  <div id="list-check" class="lists-check">
    <ul id="scheduleList">  
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block content2 %}
<div class="one-column"> 
  <p id="success" class="success"></p>
  <a href="#" name="back" id="back" tabindex="5" class="link-button" style="float:left;"><span>Back to the list</span></a>
</div>
<div class="one-column">  
  <a href="#" name="create" id="submit" tabindex="5" class="link-button" style="float:right;"><span>Tentukan Lokasi →</span></a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried to move the div to the different positions on the page but it still keep disappearing. I need a hint, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The selector used in the stylesheet:

```
#map-canvas { height: 100% }
----^
```

doesn't match the id of the map-container:

```
<div id="map_canvas">this is the map</div>
------------^
```

Comment: No, it's just my wrong when editing the code after pasting it here. I've correct it on my post, please see. Actually the the selectors are same. yet it is still not working

Comment: If it's really about sizing the div, then commenting/uncommenting the goolemap script won't affect. Yet, commenting it shows the div.

Comment: Only when it's a size-issue commenting the script will have an visible effect.